# How can I setup a printer with own ppd file?

Tags: release-loki, printer

I want to setup a network printer and I have the ppd file for it.
How can I point to my ppd file in setup process?
I tried cups web interface at localhost:631 but I got "Connection refused" answer.
I inspected the config, but the "Listen localhost:631" line was not commented so I don't know where can I enable it.

Comment: I found installed system-config-printer which seems ok.

Comment: Although **system-config-printer** working fine the ppd file not enough. The filter is missing must install something also.

Comment: What filter do you mean? And what kind of printer is it? Is it a custom PPD or are you using the file from their website? (If you can avoid downloading drivers, might be better...) Re: CUPS web install, have you tried [this guide](https://www.linux.com/blog/add-printer-linux-cups-web-utility)? You need to activate a few things before trying to connect to localhost:631

Comment: I saw errors in /var/log/cups/error_log. The type of printer is Canon imageRUNNER 1133iF, and yes, I downloaded PPD from their website. Then later I downloaded compete linux setup stuff. The setup ran with error but installed things into /opt/cel including the missing filter. Thereafter system-config-printer got the possibility to select proper ppd from install tgz. Finally I set up my printer successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

elementary OS doesn't have an option like Ubuntu of loading directly from PPD. I would recommend instead downloading the driver directly from the manufacturer's website with their install script and following elementary's prompts.

If you would like to configure additional administrative features, run `system-config-printer` in your Terminal. Alternatively, you could try a [CUPS web install](https://www.linux.com/blog/add-printer-linux-cups-web-utility) or, if you are a glutton for punishment, [CUPS install by text](http://blog.ostermiller.org/ubuntu-printer-install-command-line/).

Comment: I agree with you my experience took me to the same place. But your summary better and detailed.

Answer (score 0):

I realized there is no need the possibility the custom ppd file select if I have properly installed driver for that printer. So the elementary's config interface is perfect and nice. My question become unnecessary thank for everybody for attention.